# Testing input validation and an AJAX request with Javascript and QUnit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I have a simple web page where the user enters the name and rank of a soldier and hits submit. If the input is invalid, an appropriate error message gets displayed. Otherwise, it adds the soldier to a database and adds it to a list of current Soldiers via AJAX request.

```
//Find elements on page
var rankField = $("input[name='rank']");
var nameField = $("input[name='name']");
var submit = $("input[type='submit']");
var list = $("ul");

//attach event-handler to submit button
submit.click(function() {
  var rank = rankField.val();
  var name = nameField.val();
  onSoldierSubmitted(rank, name);
});

function onSoldierSubmitted(rank, name) {
  clearErrors();

  var rankIsValid = isValidRank(rank);
  var hasErrors = false;

  if (!rankIsValid) {
    addError('rank is invalid');
    hasErrors = true;
  };

  if (!name) {
    addError('Please enter a name for your Soldier');
    hasErrors = true;
  };

  if (hasErrors) {return;}
  appendSoldier();
};

function clearErrors() {
  $('.alert-danger').empty();
};

function addError(errorText) {
  var errorDiv = $('.alert-danger');
  var currentError = errorDiv.html();

  if (currentError) {
    currentError += '<br>';
  };

  errorDiv.html(currentError + errorText);
};

function isValidRank(rank) {
  var ranks = ['GEN', 'LTG', 'MG', 'BG', 'COL', 'LTC', 'MAJ',
      'CPT', '1LT', '2LT', 'CW5', 'CW4', 'CW3', 'CW2', 'WO1',
      'SMA', 'CSM', 'SGM', '1SG', 'MSG', 'SFC', 'SSG', 'SGT',
      'CPL', 'SPC', 'PFC', 'PV2', 'PVT']
  normalizedRank = rank.toUpperCase();
  return ranks.indexOf(normalizedRank) != -1;
};

function appendSoldier() {
  $.get("/ajax/soldier", 
  {
    rank: rankField.val(),
    name: nameField.val(),
  }).done( 
    function(data) {
      soldiers = extractSoldiersFromList(data);
      renderHTMLListFromData(soldiers);
    }
  );

  clearInput();
};

function extractSoldiersFromList(data) {
  var soldierData = $.parseJSON(data);
  var soldiers = [];

  for (var i=0; i < soldierData.length; ++i) {
    var soldier = soldierToString(soldierData[i]);
    soldiers[i] = soldier;
  }

  return soldiers;
};

function renderHTMLListFromData(data) {
  list.empty();
  elements = data;
  addSoldiersToUL(elements);
}

function addSoldiersToUL(soldiers) {
  for (var i = 0; i < soldiers.length; ++i) {
    list.append("<li>" + soldiers[i] + "</li>");
  }
}

function clearInput() {
  rankField.val('');
  nameField.val('');
}



function soldierToString(soldierDict) {
  var rank = soldierDict.rank;
  var name = soldierDict.name;

  return rank + " " + name;
};
```

(Yes, I realize I am a horrible person for using GET instead of POST for this. I was having trouble getting POST to work with my back-end.)

I'm having trouble figuring out the right unit tests for the `appendSoldier` function:

```
test("appendSoldier makes request with correct args", function() {
  sinon.spy($, 'get');
  rankField.val('PVT');
  nameField.val('Snuffy');

  appendSoldier();

  ok($.get.calledWith("/ajax/soldier", {rank: 'PVT', name: 'Snuffy'}));
  $.get.restore();
});

test("UL of Soldiers populates correctly", function() {
  renderHTMLListFromData(soldierData);
  ok(list.has('li').text('PVT Snuffy'));
});
```

My reasoning here is that unit tests aren't supposed to test anything external, so I make sure the right request gets called, and that the proper thing is done with the response. I'm unhappy with this, because it still doesn't tell me that `appendSoldier` works like it's supposed to. I guess that's just something I leave to my functional tests?

I'm also not sure about my tests for the `onSoldierSubmitted` function, which displays appropriate errors, or calls `appendSoldier` if there aren't any errors.

Here is my test for valid input:

```
test("Get request called with valid input", function() {
  sinon.spy($, "get");
  onSoldierSubmitted('pvt', 'snuffy');
  ok($.get.called, "method called");
  $.get.restore();
});
```

I'm not sure whether I ought to be uncomfortable that this tests that `appendSoldier` sends the get request, rather than testing that `appendSoldier` gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My reasoning here is that unit tests aren't supposed to test anything
>   external

I agree with that. You can't test external things like an AJAX call anyway.

> I'm unhappy with this, because it still doesn't tell me that
>   appendSoldier works like it's supposed to.

Actually, you CAN test the appendSoldier method. You need to refactor it in the following way:

```
function appendSoldier() {
    $.get("/ajax/soldier", 
    {
       rank: rankField.val(),
       name: nameField.val(),
    }).done( 
        function(data) {
            // Notice that I extracted these 2 lines of code into a separate method
            // soldiers = extractSoldiersFromList(data);
            // renderHTMLListFromData(soldiers);
            appendSoldierSuccess(data);
        }
    );

    clearInput();
};

// This is the extracted method
function appendSoldierSuccess(data) {
    soldiers = extractSoldiersFromList(data);
    renderHTMLListFromData(soldiers);
}
```

Now you can unit test the functionality in the following way (I will use Jasmine because I'm familiar with it but the concepts can be mapped to Sinon):

```
it("appendSoldierSuccess()", function() {
    var data = {};
    var soldiers = {};

    spyOn(window, 'extractSoldiersFromList').and.returnValue(soldiers);
    spyOn(window, 'renderHTMLListFromData');

    appendSoldierSuccess(data);

    expect(window.extractSoldiersFromList).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data);
    expect(window.renderHTMLListFromData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(soldiers);
});
```